# TypeError: this.authService.validateUser is not a function - NestJS

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am building a small size NestJS project. And I have constructed 2 modules including Auth and User like the code below.
But the server throws an error whenever I call the "login" api from the client. I have checked, the loginDto is fine; the payload is received successfully, but the error is raised when the server passes it to the "login" method.

```
[Nest] 42576  - 08/08/2023, 1:12:44 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] this.authService.validateUser is not a function
TypeError: this.authService.validateUser is not a function
    at AuthController.login (D:\IntelliJ_PersonalProject\son.ndc_9phone\src\auth\auth.controller.ts:22:41)
    at D:\IntelliJ_PersonalProject\son.ndc_9phone\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:38:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Here is my Auth controller:

```
import {
  Body,
  Controller,
  forwardRef,
  Inject,
  Post,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { LoginDto } from './dto/login.dto';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => UserService))
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
  ) {}

  @Post('login')
  async login(@Body() loginDto: LoginDto): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(
      loginDto.username,
      loginDto.password,
    );
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid credentials');
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

And Auth service:

```
import { forwardRef, Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { removePasswordUtil } from '../utils/removePassword.util';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => UserService))
    private readonly userService: UserService,

    private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}
  async validateUser(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.userService.findByUsername(username);
    if (user && (await this.comparePassword(password, user.password))) {
      const accessToken = this.jwtService.sign({
        username: user.username,
        email: user.email,
        permission: user.permission,
      });
      return {
        ...removePasswordUtil(user),
        accessToken,
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
  async hashPassword(password: string): Promise<string> {
    const saltRound = 10;
    return bcrypt.hash(password, saltRound);
  }

  async comparePassword(
    providedPassword: string,
    storedPassword: string,
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    return bcrypt.compare(providedPassword, storedPassword);
  }
}
```

I use forwardRef to link them together. It is seemingly ok but not working.
Many thanks!

Comment: Share the `UserService` service as well.